# Logitech M330 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: wireless, usb, mouse, logitech, usbhid

I'm trying to get the M330 mouse running but it doesn't do anything.
 
I've tried the Solaar app but it says "no Logitech receiver found".
 Though it's recognized in the system as "ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver".
 
I also tried ltunify but it says that it's missing hid-logitech-dj.

Any idea how to get the mouse running?

Comment: The mouse itself could be defective, not switched on,  or missing a battery. I have been using Logitech mice with the Unifying receiver for years with Ubuntu, and the only one that with a problem was one that was optimized for Windows, which I exchanged for a more OS-agnostic one. The M330 is advertised to work with Linux.

Comment: I tried it on a windows computer and it worked instantly.
I bought it because it said that it should work with linux but on their website is apparently no support for linux.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how but now it works :D
I installed the mdetect package and after a restart the receiver and the mouse were detected correctly.

Comment: All these mice work out of the box without additional drivers (except the "optimized for Windows" ones). My Ubuntu is so Logitech-friendly that the battery indicator also gives be the level of the mouse batteries (M705, in my case).

Comment: yes, it also showed the capacity at startup.

Comment: **Close Voters** As per OP's comment 1 hour ago: *"I'm not entirely sure how but now it works :D I installed the mdetect package and after a restart the receiver and the mouse were detected correctly."*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you solved your own problem, please consider to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-) I took the liberty to revert the change that added the answer but you can always review a post’s history through the link below it.

Answer (score 1):

same happened to me. What was missing is "hid-logitech-dj" that is found on linux-modules-extra headers. I just ran

```
sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

And rebooted and everything worked fine. If it doesn't work try reinstalling headers also:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Hope it helps